# Sequential problem for n=1, non linear regression

Tags: statistics, regression, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to understand an example in my stats course notes, the example relates to calculating the best value for the next experiment.

The function of the line is very simple:

$$ln(Y_i) = ln(\theta^*_1 + \theta^*_2x_i) + \epsilon_i$$

The example works on a previous example where point estimates have already been obtained for $\theta^*_1$ and $\theta^*_2$ These are:

$$\theta = \begin{pmatrix}
3.9963\\
2.3792
\end{pmatrix}$$

The values given already are:

```
i     y       x
1     4.11    0
2     6.32    1
3     8.21    2
4     10.43   3
5     14.29   4
6     16.78   5
```

So the question is, how to get the optimal value for $x_7$.

The equation that needs to be used is given, but doesnt make a lot of sense to me, particularly the last line, where some seemingly random numbers appear from nowhere.

Here is the notes provided:
let the px1 vector $$r_{n+1} = \frac{\delta f(x_{n+1}. \theta)}{\delta\theta}$$

$$
C_{n+1} = X_{n+1}'X_{n+1} = \begin{pmatrix}X_n\\
r_{n+1}'
\end{pmatrix}'
\begin{pmatrix}X_n\\
r_{n+1}'
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
\phi = |C_{n+1}| = |\begin{pmatrix}X_n\\
r_{n+1}'
\end{pmatrix}'
\begin{pmatrix}X_n\\
r_{n+1}'
\end{pmatrix}| = |X_n'X_n+r_{n+1}r_{n+1}'|
$$
$$
\therefore \phi = |C_{n+1} + r_{n+1}r_{n+1}'| = |C_n|(1 + r_{n+1}'C_n^{-1}r_{n+1})
$$

Here comes the example "at which value of x, 0 <= x <= 2 should the next experiment be carried out"

$$ln(Y_i) = ln(\theta^*_1 + \theta^*_2x_i) + \epsilon_i$$

$$\theta = \begin{pmatrix}
3.9963\\
2.3792
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$
X'X = \begin{bmatrix}0.11777 & 0.11660\\
0.11660 & 0.33500
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
r_7' = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\theta_1 + \theta_2 x_7} & \frac{x_7}{\theta_1 + \theta_2 x_7}\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now, while I dont exactly understand all this - I can work out what its saying. What gets me, is the next bit.

$$
\phi = \frac{12.9358 - 8.9781x_7 + 4.534x_7^2}{(3.9963 + 2.3792x_7)^2}
$$

Where did 12.9358, 8.9781, 4.534 come from?

Also, where did the devision part of this come from, above $\phi$ was calculated without any devision at all.

Finally, where did the $^2$ come from on the devisor?

Any help here would be greatly appreciated, I get the feeling its going to be very simple - I'm just missing something.

Thanks

Comment: You might get better answer here: [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @TongZhang, thanks I'll try there as well.

Comment: What's $f$ in the expression of $r_{n+1}$?

Comment: @JoeTurner It's the function $ln(y_i) = ln(\theta_1 + \theta_2x_i)$